# Showing a system error on a form after submitting via AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to find the best way in Angular to invalidate a form not due to a specific element, but due to a system-level error AFTER submission via AJAX. For example, you could put in a valid email and password (both good strings), press submit, and find out there is a system error that should trigger a generic error message on the form. Since this isn't tied to anything in the data model, what is the best way I can generically call the form 'invalid'?

```
<form name="loginForm" class="loginForm" ng-submit="loginSubmit(loginForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="login.email" required>
        <span class="error" ng-show="loginSubmit.email.$error">Required!</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.password" minlength="8" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
</form>
```

and...

```
    ngModule.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location) {

        $scope['login'] = {};

        $scope['loginSubmit'] = function(form) {

            var loginPromise = myAsyncLoginFuncYouCanAssumeWorks();

            loginPromise.done(function(){

                $location.path('/');

            });

            loginPromise.fail(function() {

                //how best to trigger a generic error in the form here?

            });

        };

    });
```

As you can see, I'd like to trigger some form-wide error state after submission. It really could be as simple as adding an invalid form class to the form, but again, I'd like to know the purest Angular way to do this.

Comment: whoops hold on everyone somehow the top half of my question got removed, give me a moment to edit

Comment: OK it's good now, sorry to anyone who saw it without the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a label to your form with your generic error which shows upon a scope variable being true when an error occurs:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="loginError">There was an error with your login details. Please check them and try again</div>
```

then when your promise fails:

```
loginPromise.fail(function () {
    $scope.loginError = true;
});
```

maybe also could be nice if you have many system messages to abstract them all out into a separate service so you can inject the systemmessages service into your controller and then simply bind:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="loginError">{{ systemMessages.loginError }}</div>
```

---

Alternatively as you use Bootstrap maybe inject the [$modal service](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and show the error message inside a popup.

- It is also important to make sure you try to use a bearer token stored in localatorage as oppose to cookies for persistence, so it doesn't get sent to the server on each request.
- Anti forgery token would also be very beneficial for SPAs.

Comment: Hmm, not working I'm afraid. Modifying the $scope attribute doesn't seem to get picked up by the `ng-show`.

Comment: (and yes don't worry I'm using tokens, just took them out for the example, thanks though)

Comment: OK I've fixed it, I had to call `$scope.$apply()` after setting `$scope.loginError`. Anyone care to enlighten me with their angular knowledge as to why I needed to do that? Something with having been called after an XHR?

Comment: I'm really glad it worked out for you. If you use Angular $q service then as its internal it would make that the digest cycle happens when your promise returns. And that's a general thing about angular, if you use native tools you get auto digest when something returns

Answer (score 0):

Your server could return some sort or error pay load with error key or error code.

```
{errors:[{key:"invalid.password"}]}
```

Assign the error response to your scope:

```
loginPromise.fail(function(response) {
    $scope.errors = response.data;
});
```

Next, add filter to translate error key/code into error messages:

```
angular.module('mtApp').filter('errorFilter', function() {
    return function(e) {
        if (e === 'invalid.password') {
            return 'Invalid password, please try again.';
        }
    };
});
```

Finally, display the appropriated errors as a list:

```
<div ng-show="errors">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="e in errors">{{e.key | errorFilter}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Optionally, you can reuse this same "$scope.erros" object combined to ng-class and control the CSS of each field with error.

Comment: you may be better off using a switch in your filter function